# Why in address space's private regions so many zero bytes?

Tags: windows, process, operating-system, virtual-address-space, address-space

I'm examining process's address space under windows. When i see content of private regions, i wonder, because there are so many zero bytes (in some regions more than 95%). If more of private regions don't used while application is running, why they aren't only reserved or free?

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiprocessing systems tend to initialize memory for security purposes. Usually, this is to zero. AIX at one time liked to initialize memory to 0xDEADBEAF.

Comment: I know that on there's an thread, with 0 priority, and it sets sets all uninitialized bits to 0. You say about this? I just want to know who and when initialized that bytes to 0.